# How to filter the same set of data in a view via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `message` model with each message having both a `status` and `context`(type) attribute that I'd like to filter by. The `index` view currently displays all messages as intended. My question is, what is the BEST way (with example if possible) to filter these results via AJAX?

The reason I'd like to do AJAX is so that I can click links to different statuses/context-types and it can replace the table currently displaying all `messages` (through a `@message.each` call in the view) without having to have 10 different actions with 10 different partials only because it just doesn't seem like the rails way.

Setup is as follows:

```
# Message Model ## I have included the attributes and all possible values for the sake of completion ## 
message.status = ['New', 'Responded', 'Follow-up Required', 'Resolved']
message.context = ['Account Activation', 'Billing', 'Client Services', 'General Inquiry', 'Technical Support']


# Message Controller #
def index
  @messages = Message.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

# messages/index.html.erb #
renders a partial containing a table with @messages.each iteration
```

I'm still quite unexperienced with AJAX and have tried to do it creating 9 different partials and having them replace one another upon clicking a link, or having 9 different controller methods for a single index page just changing the `@messages` variable, also have toyed with the idea of using AJAX to update the `@messages` variable based on what link is clicked but none of these seem like the "Rails" way to do it.

Any and all suggestions welcome and super bonus points to anyone with a solution that can AJAXify pagination as well but I'm kind of assuming that if I can use AJAX to display the tables correctly, then paginating via AJAX shouldn't be too hard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm kinda getting a little bit of information overload.  Would it be possible to simplify the question?  You have an endpoint that takes in some variable information and returns results depending upon the variable input.  Can you describe just that part, and what issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Apologies, I often see questions where people ask for more information so I try to avoid that. Essentially, I have an `index view` displaying all `messages`, I'd like to filter the messages by choice of attribute via AJAX so the user doesn't have to leave the page. Total messages will grow in size over time thus requiring pagination. I don't know the best way to achieve that without repeating code for every filter, so my question is how would I be able to do it? Thanks

Comment: So on page load **all** messages are present?

Comment: Correct, initial load has all messages, while not leaving that page (if possible) I would like to filter based on attributes (from what I know that would require something along the lines of a `Message.where(status: "xx")`  call in a controller)

Comment: Well, if your initial page load has all the messages, you've already taken the performance hit to return all that data.  I would think given that situation it would be more performat to simply show/hide results based on the filter, rather than making further ajax calls to return data you already have.

Comment: As you can see above, the initial load is paginated to only display 15 results and then 15 for each page, however ALL messages are loaded into the `@messages` instance variable which I am using to access it. My thought process was maybe to change what is loaded into `@messages` 
via AJAX in order to not duplicate the same view multiple times with just a different instance variable but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some brain storming, I decided to use a `case` statement within my `index` action to update the `@messages` array via two params passed through the links that have the filter options, `params[:status]` and `params[:context]`. I pulled the table as well as the filter links into two separate partials, and render those each time (via `index.js.erb`) any of the filter links are clicked.

**`index - MessagesController`**

```
def index

  status = params[:status]
  context = params[:context]

  case status
    when "New"
      @msg_status = "New"
    when "Responded"
      @msg_status = "Responded"
    when "Follow_up", "Follow-up Required"
      @msg_status = "Follow-up Required"
    when "Resolved"
      @msg_status = "Resolved"
  end

  case context
    when "Account_Activation"
      @msg_context = "Account Activation"
    when "Billing"
      @msg_context = "Billing"
    when "Client_Services"
      @msg_context = "Client Services"
    when "General_Inquiry"
      @msg_context = "General Inquiry"
    when "Technical_Support"
      @msg_context = "Technical Support"
  end

  if @msg_status && @msg_context
    msg = Message.where(status: "#{@msg_status}")
    @messages = msg.where(context: "#{@msg_context}").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  elsif @msg_status
    @messages = Message.where(status: "#{@msg_status}").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  elsif @msg_context
    @messages = Message.where(context: "#{@msg_context}").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  else
    @messages = Message.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**`_message_table.html.erb`** - partial displaying messages

```
<% @messages.each do |msg| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

Example of link passing **`params[:status]`**

```
<%= link_to(url_for(messages_path(status: 'New')), remote: true) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> New <span class="label label-success pull-right"><%= Message.where(status: "New").count %></span>
<% end %>
```

Example of link passing **`params[:context]`** - inside links partial so they are refreshed each time a status link is clicked

```
<%= link_to(url_for(messages_path(status: "#{@msg_status}", context: 'Technical_Support')), remote: true) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Technical Support
<% end %>
```

Rendering of both partials are handled by `index.js.erb`.

This is most "rails" way I could think of doing it while also staying as DRY and RESTful as possible. The above works perfectly for what I was trying to achieve but if anyone has any ideas to make it simpler/cleaner/more "rails" then I'm always open to suggestions. Thanks.